# Crashed when scroll UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview

When i scroll UIScrollView with iOS 5.1. It's works fine but when scroll with iOS 6.0 the app has crashed. But i do not error line code. this is exception fired:

```
2012-09-25 11:47:36.255 Attack[4515:c07] Stack Trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0061802e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02c8de7e objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00617deb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   QuartzCore                          0x00a31a75 _ZN2CA5Layer10set_boundsERKNS_4RectEb + 213
    4   QuartzCore                          0x00a31d1e -[CALayer setBounds:] + 154
    5   UIKit                               0x0190e7a1 -[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] + 336
    6   UIKit                               0x01920748 -[UIScrollView setBounds:] + 5493
    7   UIKit                               0x01920c9d -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 728
    8   UIKit                               0x019275ec -[UIScrollView _updatePanGesture] + 2873
    9   UIKit                               0x0192b0e7 -[UIScrollView handlePan:] + 305
    10  UIKit                               0x01b9389a _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 139
    11  UIKit                               0x01b929db -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 333
    12  UIKit                               0x01b9411f -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 46
    13  UIKit                               0x01b96d6d ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0543 + 57
    14  UIKit                               0x01b96cec _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 331
    15  UIKit                               0x01b8ea68 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 1348
    16  UIKit                               0x018fbfc2 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1283
    17  UIKit                               0x018fc4a3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 98
    18  UIKit                               0x018da3aa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    19  UIKit                               0x018cbcf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x03045df9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x03045ad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0058dbf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0058d962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x005bebb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x005bdf44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x005bde1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x030447e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x03044668 GSEventRun + 104
    29  UIKit                               0x018c965c UIApplicationMain + 1211
    30  Attack                              0x00002e7a main + 170
    31  Attack                              0x00002d85 start + 53
)
2012-09-25 11:47:36.256 Attack[4515:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [nan 0; 640 480]'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Does anyone know line code what is it mean? : `-[UIScrollView setBounds:] + 5493`.

Comment: I've had this issue when I applied invalid scale transform with `0` as `sz` value.