# Crash when moving from a complex scroll view page

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview, rotation

iOS7, iPad, universal app. UITabBarViewController with 4 pages. One page (#2) is pretty complicated with a scroll view (enough to hold three screens for horizontal scrolling) and three table views inside it on each page.

I've got the following scenario to reproduce the crash, but I have no idea where to dig for fix:
- Initially app starts with page #1 being active
- User goes to the page #2
- Rotates the device, does some data refresh
- Goes back to the page #1

I can see that viewWillDissapear is called for page #2, but viewDidDisappear is never called. I'm getting a crash in main.c with the following stack trace:

```
2014-08-07 16:07:40.379 Time[10691:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: [768 nan; 768 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0258f1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x022328e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0258efbb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   QuartzCore                          0x028f5a3b _ZN2CA5Layer10set_boundsERKNS_4RectEb + 267
    4   QuartzCore                          0x028f5d06 -[CALayer setBounds:] + 135
    5   UIKit                               0x00f50781 -[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] + 358
    6   UIKit                               0x00f6d627 -[UIScrollView setBounds:] + 1036
    7   UIKit                               0x00f6db9b -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 690
    8   UIKit                               0x00f86ad8 -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:tramplingDragFlags:] + 423
    9   UIKit                               0x00f86b7e -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:] + 57
    10  UIKit                               0x00f6e6b4 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 106
    11  UIKit                               0x00f5c109 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 763
    12  UIKit                               0x00f5c109 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 763
    13  UIKit                               0x00f5c109 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 763
    14  UIKit                               0x00f5c109 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 763
    15  UIKit                               0x00f5c109 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 763
    16  UIKit                               0x00f5c109 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 763
    17  UIKit                               0x00f5396f __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 158
    18  Foundation                          0x01fe568c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 107
    19  Foundation                          0x01e753c5 -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 48
    20  UIKit                               0x00f53830 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 313
    21  UIKit                               0x00f51b0a __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 226
    22  UIKit                               0x00f5170a -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 264
    23  UIKit                               0x00ff1ba6 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 634
    24  UIKit                               0x00ff2df9 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 3006
    25  UIKit                               0x00ff2233 -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 62
    26  UIKit                               0x00ff1fd3 -[UITransitionView transition:toView:] + 123
    27  UIKit                               0x01049526 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 1438
    28  UIKit                               0x01048943 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 63
    29  UIKit                               0x01044bed -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 281
    30  UIKit                               0x01044acc -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 180
    31  UIKit                               0x0104883f -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 312
    32  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02244880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    33  UIKit                               0x00ef43b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    34  UIKit                               0x00ef4345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    35  UIKit                               0x011b8629 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 479
    36  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0224482b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    37  UIKit                               0x00ef43b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    38  UIKit                               0x00ef4345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    39  UIKit                               0x00ff5bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    40  UIKit                               0x00ff5fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    41  UIKit                               0x00ff5c06 -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 48
    42  UIKit                               0x011bd23d -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 123
    43  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02244880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    44  UIKit                               0x00ef43b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    45  UIKit                               0x00ef4345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    46  UIKit                               0x00ff5bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    47  UIKit                               0x00ff5fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    48  UIKit                               0x00ff5243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    49  UIKit                               0x00f33ddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    50  UIKit                               0x00f349d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    51  UIKit                               0x00f065f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    52  UIKit                               0x00ef0353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    53  CoreFoundation                      0x0251877f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    54  CoreFoundation                      0x0251810b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    55  CoreFoundation                      0x025351ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    56  CoreFoundation                      0x025349d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    57  CoreFoundation                      0x025347eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    58  GraphicsServices                    0x048235ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    59  GraphicsServices                    0x0482342b GSEventRun + 104
    60  UIKit                               0x00ef2f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    61  Time                                0x001d3832 main + 130
    62  libdyld.dylib                       0x02e26701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any idea where to look for a problem?

Comment: Looks like you are setting the bounds of a UIView using a value in the CGRect that is not a number.  Are you setting the bounds of any views during these transitions?

Comment: What do you mean "these" transitions? I do some manual layout when rotating, but I don't do anything special when going from one tabbar page to another

Comment: Transitions from page 1 → page 2 → page 1.  Someone else had the exact same issue but it doesn't appear to be solved: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12576397/3055415 Based on the comment, are you applying a scale transform?

Comment: No. I don't do any custom stuff when going from one page to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Watch out for some instances of `UIScrollView` inside your page that has 0 size (width/height).

I think I figured this out.

As part of my complex view there was a `UIScrollView` (let's call it `SV1`) and at some point I needed to hide it. To hide that scrollview I set its frame to the CGRectZero.

During leaving the page the superview (`V2`) of that zero-ed scrollview was being removed from its superview and for some reason that was causing the crash (I verified that by trying to remove V2 manually during `viewWillDisappear` and I was able to get exact same crash.

To fix it - instead of assigning CGRectZero to the scrollview SV1, I simply removed it from superview V2 at that time (when I needed to hide it). This solve my problem. Hopefully it will help somebody else.